# How to match escaped char like "\a's" saved in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, string-matching, htmlspecialchars

I have name field in table which have entry like "kishan\'s field". How can i match this value to external input "kishan's field"??[image]

Comment: question is: why did you let those in to the db in the first place. You did not foresee that I guess

Comment: Perhaps just run an update statement to strip out those unused/superfluous escape characters. Like @Fred-ii- suggests though, fix whatever code is causing those to come in otherwise you'll be playing never-ending clean up.

Comment: Data itself is a symptom of incorrect escaping on insertion and the `htmlspecialchars` tag doesn't make it better. Whatever, the question itself is not clear. What does "match `"kishan\'s field"` to `"kishan's field"` mean exactly? Do you want to search the latter and find the former?

Comment: Alvaro you are right i must escape special chars while saving to table

Comment: @AtulKumar Perhaps you should **not**—at least not twice as you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Untested: UPDATE some_table SET some_name_field = REPLACE(some_name_field, '\', '')